# Mediation and binary logistic regression - is this even possible with R?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, logistic-regression, mediator

I am a beginner and have my term paper due next week. As I said, I'm carrying out a binary logistic regression with Mediator. I wanted to calculate the effect using mediate(), but I get an error:

> Error in mediate(Model2, Model3, treat = "Sat_dem", mediator = "Corona", : number of observations do not match between mediator and outcome models

To understand, I did this:

```
Model1 <- glm(data$second_vote ~ data$Sat_dem, data = data, family = "binomial")
Model2 <- glm(data$Corona ~ data$Sat_dem + data$Gender + data$Income + data$Education +     data$Religion, data = data)
Model3 <- glm(data$second_vote ~ data$Sat_dem + data$Corona + data$Gender + data$Income + data$Education + data$Religion, data = data, family = "binomial")
results <- mediate(Model2, Model3, treat = "Sat_dem", mediator = "Corona", covariates = c("Gender", "Income", "Education", "Religion") ~ NULL)
```

All packages are available. I first tried swapping Model2 and Model3 into the term, which didn't work. Then I tried to split the file:

```
set.seed(42)
split <- sample.split(data, SplitRatio = 0.8)
train_data <- subset(data, split == TRUE)
test_data <- subset(data, split == FALSE)
```

First came this:

```
Error in quantile.default(y, probs = seq(0, 1, length = groups)) : missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
```

I really tried to fix this problem somehow, but it just didn't work. Then I tried again manually:

```
set.seed(42)
split_manual <- sample(2, nrow(data), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
train_data_manual <- data[split_manual == 1, ]
```

and only Model2 shows Error:

```
Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, :
NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(y, mu) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(eta, offset) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(y, mu) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Even if I use the original variables, I get an error. Now I'm wondering if this is even possible in the way I imagined?

Comment: From the error, I'd make sure that model2 and model3 are fit on the same data e.g. the same number of complete cases. Also fitting your models like `Model1 <- glm(data$second_vote ~ data$Sat_dem, data = data, family = "binomial")` is generally a poor idea; use the `data=` argument only instead e.g. `Model1 <- glm(second_vote ~ Sat_dem, data = data, family = "binomial")`

Comment: If the variables have different missing values then the syntax `data$column_name` will produce vectors of different lengths. Generally speaking, it is always a bad idea to include the data in a formula, remove `data$` from the calls to the fitting functions since you already use argument `data = data`. This will keep the complete case first, then fit the model.

Comment: @user20650 and Rui Barradas, I thank you for the help! I didn't realize that this would cause a problem. But I solved it now by dropping rows that have NAs for any of the variables and then specifying the variables without data$. Thanks!